# Why is viewport width being ignored by browsers?

Tags: html, css, browser

How use the meta tag viewport to set the size?

The tag appears to be ignored whatever value is entered.

I think I'm wrong because this code is ignored by both desktop and mobile browsers

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=920, initial-scale=1">
```

Is there anything I missed?
How to set the viewport to a specific width?

Example code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=920, initial-scale=1">

    <script>
        window.onload = function () {

            var viewportWidth = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth;

            var text = "Viewport width: " + viewportWidth + // 1536
            "<br>screen.width: " + screen.width + // 1536
            "<br>window.devicePixelRatio: " + window.devicePixelRatio + // 1.25
            "<br>screen.width * devicePixelRatio: " + window.screen.width*window.devicePixelRatio // 1920

            document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = text;
        };
    </script>
    <style>
        html, body {padding: 0px; margin: 0px;}
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <h1 id="info"></h1>
    <div id="screen"></div>

    <div style="width: 1920px; height: 100px; background-color: yellow;">1920 x 100</div>
    <br>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/h1Vr7E4.png" alt="" srcset="">

</body>

</html>
```